# PHP and MySQL query - multiple criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem with the code listed below where I'm running a query on a database based on search criteria the user may have selected on a form.

At the moment, querying the database just on the author's name works fine. But if I uncomment the rest of the if-else statements, none of the queries work. I just get a blank table back with no results returned.

I've tried each if/else statement individually with the others commented out and they all work fine on their own, but not when they're all uncommented.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_no IS NOT NULL";


if ($_POST['author']) 
$query .= " AND '$author' = author";

/*
else if ($_POST['author'] AND $_POST['year']) 
$query .= " AND '$author' = author AND '$year' = year";
*/


/*
else if ($_POST['cover_art']) {
$query .= " AND '$cover_art' = cover_art";

}
*/

/*

else if ($_POST['interior_art']) {
$query .= " AND '$cover_art' = cover_art";

}

else {
// do something else
}
*/
```

Comment: First off: you really ought to be using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or the equivalent for your database. Secondly, have you tried printing out the queries and running them manually? Perhaps they simply don't match anything in the database. Thirdly, are you checking for errors on all database functions that return errors? Finally, where are your variables $author, $cover_art, and $year set? You don't show that in this code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried running the queries manually and they check out fine. The $author, $cover_art and $year variables are declared just ahead of the code posted as follows:                   $author=$_POST['author'];
  $cover_art=$_POST['cover_art'];
  $interior_art=$_POST['interior_art'];
  $year = $_POST['year'];

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

```
$author='Bred';
$year='2012';
$cover_art='';

$queryA=array();

if ($author<>'') $queryA []= "'$author' = author";
if ($year<>'') $queryA []= "'$year' = year";
if ($cover_art<>'') $queryA []= "'$cover_art' = cover_art";

$query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_no IS NOT NULL";
if(count($queryA)>0) $query.=' AND '.implode(' AND ',$queryA);

echo $query;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I notice in the code you've posted that you've hard-coded values for author, year and cover_art. What if I wanted to use the values that were obtained via the form using the POST method?

Comment: This code is very difficult to read. Consider using `empty()` and braces for `if` statements. Also, why would you first check if there are books at all?

Comment: @JamesWhelan just use if(isset($_POST['author']) $author=$_POST['author']; else $author='';... etc. Take care about mysql injection.

Comment: @andy yes, but I use the original code and make some small changes. it would be easier to see changes